# Github Action - Triggers

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to run a workflow called "Deploy" after a workflow called "Build" completes successfully. However, on top of that condition, "Deploy" workflow can only run if I'm in branch "prod". How can I configure this condition in Github Actions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a job only on a certain branch, add a condition like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/prod'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo hello
```

Note that the `github.ref` has a prefix `refs/heads/`.

Comment: but what about running the "Deploy" job after the "build" job if I'm in branch "prod"? Note, that the "Deploy" job must run if the "build" job succeeds